# Best approach for populating nested data

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

First, I would just like to say that I have went down a little rabbit hole with this one, to the point where I feel I may have missed a simpler solution. So apologies if there is one and it is screaming at me!

So the problem:

I have a set of user data, containing, username, forename, surname, active.

I am presenting this user data initially using an accordion component. Which takes sections and iterates over them, displaying the data provided from the sections input. This sections array would be populated with data fetched from a backend API, but transformed into sections like so:

Component TS

```js
public sections = [
    {
       id: 1,
       username: 'john-doe',
       forename: 'John',
       surname: 'Doe'
    },
    { 
       id: 2,
       username: 'jane-doe',
       forename: 'Jane',
       surname: 'Doe'
    },
}];
```

Component HTML

```html
<app-ui-accordion [sections]="sections"></app-ui-accordion>
```

Accordion Component

```html
<div class="ui-accordion__panel" *ngFor="let item of data">
    <a class="ui-accordion__heading">{{ item.username }}</a>
    <div class="ui-accordion__content">
        ... 
        Code for showing usernanme, forename, surname.
        ...

        [But also would like to show extended table data here when user clicks ui-accordion__heading]
    </div>
</div>
```

Each `ui-accordion__heading` handles a click event which opens ui-accordion__content by setting a `ui-accordion--active` class.

What I am trying to achieve is, is to somehow be able to click the panel heading, have the panel__content div open, then either through some magic routing or lazy loading components - be able to then populate a table with a users roles.

So the panels are working as expected but I am just struggling with the correct approach, if there even is one in this case.

Am I mis-using the UiAccordion component, such that reusable presentation components shouldn't be this complex?

Repeating router-outlet for every iteration and then subscribing to the paramMap, so that the component is able to ngOnInit with different a user ID.

Passing in a template and using *ngTemplateOutlet to render. But this does not happen lazily and all data is populated immediately.

EDIT: I am using an accordion component because it fits to a design spec where there is a master-detail type display, but rather than detail being an additional router, it is just hidden from view. Forename, surname, active is the detail, and username is the master. Then user's roles is the detail-detail

Comment: Why not go with an ui-accordion__panel inside the ui-accordion__panel-content ? And then you can play with the `let i = index` of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as as adding an index to allow lazy loading of nested content onclick. see this post
[How to create a lazy load treeview in Angular 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55181236/how-to-create-a-lazy-load-treeview-in-angular-7)

Comment: I think this addresses the problem, definitely a more simplified way. However, I am unsure how to construct this using the presentation component. I wonder am I over complicating the problem by trying to be too generic with this?